# NgRX store select returns store state instead of data

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm trying to implement ngrx v4 to my angular project and struggling with getting data from ngrx store. I wrote Actions, Reducer and Effects based on provided api documentation on [github page](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) and it seems to me everything is correct but instead of data I get store State like this:

[image]

So I appreciate if somebody could help me to figure out where my mistake is. Thanks in advance. My code below

interface.ts

```
export interface Category {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  used: boolean;
}
```

actions.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import {Category} from '../categories';

export const GET_CATEGORIES  = '[Category] Get data';
export const GET_CATEGORIES_ERROR = '[Category] Get data error';
export const GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS  = '[Category] Get data success ';

export class GetCategories implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_CATEGORIES;
}
export class GetCategoriesError implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_CATEGORIES_ERROR;
}
export class GetCategoriesSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS;
  constructor(public payload: Category[]) { }
}

export type All = GetCategories | GetCategoriesSuccess | GetCategoriesError
```

reducer.ts

```
import * as CategoriesActions from './categories.actions';
import {Category} from '../categories';

export type Action = CategoriesActions.All;

export function categoriesReducer (state: Category[], action: Action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case CategoriesActions.GET_CATEGORIES: {
      return state;
    }

    case CategoriesActions.GET_CATEGORIES_ERROR: {
      return state;
    }

    case CategoriesActions.GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS: {
      return action.payload;
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

effects.ts

```
...
import {CategoriesService} from './categories.service';

@Injectable()
export class CategoriesEffects {

  @Effect() getCategories$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType('GET_CATEGORIES')
    .mergeMap(action => this.categoriesService.getCategories()
      .map(data => ({type: 'GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS', payload: data }))
      .catch(() => of({ type: 'GET_CATEGORIES_ERROR', payload: {message: 'Oops something is wrong'} }))
    );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private categoriesService: CategoriesService
  ) {}
}
```

component.ts

```
interface CategoryState {
  categories: Category[]
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.css'],
})

export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$: Observable<Category[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<CategoryState>) {

    console.log(this.categories$) // undefined

    this.categories$ = this.store.select('categories');

    console.log(this.categories$) // store state
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCategories()
  }

  getCategories () {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: 'GET_CATEGORIES' });
  } 
}
```

module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot({ categories: categoriesReducer }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([CategoriesEffects]),
  ],
  declarations: [ CategoriesComponent ],
  providers:    [ CategoriesService ],
  entryComponents: []
})
export class CategoriesModule {}
```

Comment: you should `subscribe` to the state to get the data

Comment: @Aravind I'm not sure that is correct, cause neither api neither any tutorial about ngrx doesn't tell about this.

Comment: can you follow this [**medium post**](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/setting-up-storemodule-in-ngrx-4-0-b7c60732aa64)

Comment: @Aravind I checked that post there is nothing about Effects or subscribe Store state.

Comment: are you available in team viewer or chrom remote desktop. so i can help you by debugging?

Comment: without `subscribe` store will return an `Observeble` you should subscribe in the component by store.select('').subsribe(data=>{}) or thanks to ASYNC pipe in the template

Comment: @AnouarMokhtari my template  `<div>Current categories: <br>
    <ul><li *ngFor="let category of (categories$ | async)">{{category.name}}</li></ul>
  </div>`, async doesn't help

Comment: @AnouarMokhtari `this.store.select('categories')
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data) 
      })` console log returns undefined, does it mean something wrong with my store?

Comment: @Aravind `this.store.select('categories') .subscribe(data => { console.log(data) })` console log returns undefined, does it mean something wrong with my store?

Comment: I guess the problem is in your `@effect` indeed try to return a new action `Success` with `return` like that  .map((categories_list : Category[]) =>
      {  return new LoadCategoriesSuccessAction(categories_list);
      } );

Comment: are you not available for debug? can you add more info about your store structure and reducer factory?

Comment: this code will launch a new Action, after we can retrieve data in your `Reducer`; try to debug your code inside each Reducer maybe that s help you because before the `store` got `data` ..it s spent in Reducer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `ngrx/store : 4.1`

- You should have a reducer factory to inject the reducers to the StoreModule

  ```
  import {ActionReducerMap} from '@ngrx/store';
  import {Category} from '../categories';
  import * as categoryReducer from './categories.reducer';

  export interface CategoryState {
    categories: Category[]
  }

  export interface AppStates {
    categoryState: CategoryState;
  }

  export const categoryReducers: ActionReducerMap<AppStates> = {
    categoryState: categoryReducer.reducer
  };
  ```
- Use the reducer factory to inject into the module as below,

  ```
  StoreModule.forRoot(categoryReducers)
  import {categoryReducers} from './store/categories.reducer.factory';
  ```
- Your constructor should take the `AppStates` as the type for `Store` as

  ```
  constructor(private store: Store<AppStates>){}
  ```
- And your effect should use be

  ```
  @Effect() 
  getCategories$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
      .ofType(CategoriesActions.GET_CATEGORIES)
      .mergeMap(action => this.categoriesService.getCategories()
            .map(data => ({type: CategoriesActions.GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS, payload: data }))
            .catch(() => of({ type: CategoriesActions.GET_CATEGORIES_ERROR, payload: {message: 'Oops something is wrong'} }))
      );
  ```

Answer (score 6):

This isn't an answer to antonyboom's specific issue, but rather a helpful hint for others who arrived here based on the title of the question: it appears that NGRX's Store.select will return the store observable as a default in case it can't find data at the path you've queried. think Apache 404 error.

I had to revise my type casting to ensure typescript wasn't enforcing an incorrect store structure. specifically, note that the interface specify for the first argument into your reducer is not the same as that which you inject into your components.

Model, Reducer:

```
export interface AppState {
  textinput: string;
  integerVariable: number;
}
export interface State {
  app: AppState;
}

export function reducerFunction (
  state: AppState,
  action: Actions
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
  app: reducerFunction
})
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    this.currentSlide = store.select(s => s.app.textinput);
}
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This has happened to me twice

Answer (score 2):

The name provided in reducer import part MUST be same as the parameter name of the `State`

Store:

```
export interface AppState {
  logs: string[];
}

export interface AppStore{
  appState: AppState; // (1)
}
```

app.module.ts import:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
  appState: reducerFunction // (2)
})
```

So, (1) and (2) (`appState`) MUST be same.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to solve this problem for the last few hours.